# Python Overwriting text in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, overwrite, tkinter-canvas

I'm having some trouble updating the countdown timer text printed on a canvas. My current code leaves the area where the text should be blank.

I've tried placing it in various places, but they all lead to no effect or the same effect I described above. Removing the `canvas.delete` function just leads to the new time being written on top of the old one.

Here is my current code:

```
def cdtimerr():
    global cdtimer
    cdtimer -= 1
    cdtext = canvas.create_text(510, 6, text=cdtimer, font="Ubuntu 29 bold", anchor = NW) 
    if cdtimer == 0 :
        canvas.delete(ALL)
        scorescreen()
    else:
        canvas.after(1000, cdtimerr)
        canvas.after(1000, canvas.delete(cdtext))
```

Also, how would I go about terminating the timer prematurely if I pressed an exit button on the canvas which loads another screen? Currently, if I load another screen the timer still continues.

Comment: your indentation is messed up in your code sample. Is all that code part of `cdtimer`, or is some of it at the global scope?

Comment: I think it got messed up after I had copied it to my question because it is indented correctly and works in pydev..
fixed it now though, didn't notice it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cancel timer. Save return value of `after`, call `after_cancel` with saved value.

```
from Tkinter import *

remain = 11
_timer = None
def cdtimerr():
    global remain, _timer
    remain -= 1
    cdtext = canvas.create_text(510, 6, text=remain, font="Ubuntu 29 bold", anchor=NW) 
    if remain == 0:
        canvas.delete(ALL)
    else:
        _timer = canvas.after(1000, lambda: (canvas.delete(cdtext), cdtimerr()))

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1024x768')
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
_timer = canvas.after(0, cdtimerr)
Button(root, text='Cancel', command=lambda: canvas.after_cancel(_timer)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, was able to make it work perfectly in the program.